# Why doesnt my Custom Splash screen display when I access my Android application from an App Shortcut

Tags: android, android-splashscreen, android-appshortcut

I have added an animated Splash Screen to my current Android application using

```
  implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0"
```

This works fine and my custom splash screen is shown as expected.

However my application also has multiple App Shortcuts that deeplinks into my application and when the user clicks on any app shortcut my custom splash screen is not displayed, the default system supplied splash screen is triggered, e.g. the app icon is shown.

How do i get my custom animated app splash screen to display irrespective of how my app is accessed?